# electric potential at the other end of diode

Tags: potential, semiconductor-physics

I was brushing my basics about diode & got stuck at a point...my question is

1. Consider a diode let the positive terminal of the diode be connected to +ve of battery
   [image]

Now in the figure let the base be open & Ic=0mA. Now when i measure the voltage across point A w.r.t ground the voltage reading will be **+Vcc** .I don't understand how the voltage is +Vcc, I mean how is the potential at point **A** equal to **+Vcc**.Can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 1):

For a diode, no voltage means no current (and vice versa).  That is, an operating point of a diode is (0 V, 0 A).    So with $I_c=0$, there is no voltage dropped across the diode, so point $A$ is at the same potential as $V_{cc}$